# Extracting Help

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

can someone please help.
I first entered the command:

```
wget https://www.snort.org/rules/community -O ~/community.tar.gz
```

at the end it came up:

```
Resolving .tar.gz (.tar.gz)...failed:Name or service not known. 
wget: Unable to resolve host address '.tar.gz'
FINISHED --2018-09-28 19:20
Total wall clock time: 2.1s
Downloaded: 1 files, 309k in 0.9s (335 KB/s)
```

Next I want to extract the rules (files) so I can copy them to a different folder using:

```
sudo tar -xvf ~/community.tar.gz -C ~/
```

but it comes up

```
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this so I can copy them to another folder, if anyone knows how I can sort this, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry i'm new to askubuntu and wasn't sure what I should pick.

Comment: Thanks PerlDuck for making that easier to read.

Comment: You're welcome. But please post EXACTLY what you entered and what the result was. When I copy-and-paste your `wget` command then it downloads a (seemingly) valid *.tar.gz file. You can easily copy the text in your terminal (by just selecting it with the mouse) and then paste it into the post (by clicking the middle mouse-button). Then select the text in the post and hit CTRL-K (or click the `{}` icon in the toolbar) to mark it as literal text.

Comment: commands work perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies and help, someone mentioned I had a typo and that seems to have fixed the issue, even though I couldn't see it to start with.

Comment: @Helllp That's why copy-and-pasting the commands and their output is so important. Often just one innocent looking space makes a huge difference ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in the `wget` command - maybe this:

```
wget https://www.snort.org/rules/community -O ~/community .tar.gz
                                                         ^ space here
```

But this is not reflected in the question.

Comment: Thank you didn't notice that